# Rails on ubuntu not found - but in list of my gem installs

Tags: ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rvm

I'm trying to install rails on ubuntu, doing so using rvm and not the apt-get which is outdated.
so far I had no troubles - rvm working good, so does gem and ruby.
but when I'm trying to load rails ubuntu gives me this message:

```
The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * rails
 * ruby-railties-3.2
```

how can I make my ubuntu recognize rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your bashrc file if its not there already

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you install Rails?

If not, run

```
gem install rails
```

Comment: I am also suffering to the rails installation. Would you give me a complete step-by-step installation of Rails?If you agree I can share my email id. I am on Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Did you install it in a project directory with bundle? In that case, try `bundle exec rails` rather than just `rails`.

Comment: I don't have bundle installed at all.

and here is the guide Iv'e been following: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm

Comment: Did you try closing your terminal and opening it again? It could be that your rvm is not completely loaded yet.

Comment: yes I have. also reload bash by "source ~/.bashrc". But now I looked into ~/.rvm/bin and rails is not there. I guess that may cause the problem?